# What method should I use for comparing the performance of two classifiers statistically?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

1) Based on this paper: Evaluating the Replicability of Significance Tests for
Comparing Learning Algorithms by Remco R. Bouckaert and Eibe Frank, I conclude that "using 100 runs of random subsampling in conjunction with Nadeau and Bengio’s corrected resampled t-test" would be a good approach for statistically comparing 2 classifiers. In this paper they have talked about accuracy as the performance metric.

2) I have also seen in literature, that many people use the ROCKIT software or the DeLong test for comparing the AUC of 2 methods to say whether one method is significantly better than the other or not.

Now, I am confused. My two algorithms (say SVM and Naive Bayes) output probability scores. I can convert them to binary based on a specific threshold and use the first method (using 100 stratified shuffle split), or just use the second method using the probability scores (just run a 10 fold CV, concat the scores of the 10 folds and input to ROCKIT or DeLong).

Which one should I use for my statistical test? Which one is more appropriate?

Comment: I provided links to some resources in [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360336/my-deep-learning-model-improved-is-the-difference-significant/360359#360359).

Comment: @sebp I just looked at the paper by Demsar. The following sentence says "As such, [non-parametric tests] they can be applied to classification accuracies, error ratios or any other measure for evaluation of classifiers, including even model sizes and computation times". So, I should basically take the 100 runs of random subsampling, calculate the AUC for each test split, and then apply the wilcoxon signed rank test on the AUC differences of the two models over the 100 runs?

Comment: When I use the DeLong test, the results are insignificant, and when I use the Wilcoxon test it is extremely significant (p < 10^-6). Which one should I trust?